# Почему for цикл не доходит до последнего элемента массива?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть `js/jquery`:

```
$('.close-btn').on('click', function() {
    var citRows =  $( droppableArea ).find('.cit-pickup-row');
    for (var i = 0;i < citRows.length;i++) {
        citRow = citRows[i]
        $(citRow).appendTo($('.cit-pickup-table-body'));
        $(citRow).css({
                        "margin": "0",
                        "border": "none",
                        "border-bottom": "1px solid #dfdfdf",
                        "border-radius": "0px"
                    })
        $('.cit-pickup-row').draggable('disable');
    }
    for (j =0; j < citTransactions.length; j++) {
        citTransact = citTransactions[j];
        citTransactions.remove(citTransact);
    }
    $('.reconciliation-modal').hide();
})
```

Моя функция `remove`:

```
Array.prototype.remove = function() {
var what, a = arguments, L = a.length, ax;
while (L && this.length) {
    what = a[--L];
    while ((ax = this.indexOf(what)) !== -1) {
        this.splice(ax, 1);
    }
}
return this;
};
```

И почему-то во втором цикле `for`, он не доходит до последнего элемента массива(даже не начинается итерация). В чём может быть проблема, и каково её решение?
**UPD**
Место, где заполняется массив `citTransactions`:

```
$('.modal-droppable-area').droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        window.droppableArea = $( this ).find('.droppable-content');
        $( this ).find('.droppable-content-info').hide();
        $(dragTarget).appendTo($(droppableArea));
        window.citTransactionId = $( dragTarget ).data('cit-transaction-id');
        window.citTransactionAmount = $( dragTarget ).find('.cit-amount')[0].innerText.replace(',', '');
        window.citTransaction = {'id':citTransactionId, 'amount':citTransactionAmount};
        citTransactions.push(citTransaction);
        console.log(citTransactions);
        recDiscrepancy.innerText = numberWithCommas((Number(recDiscrepancy.innerText.replace(',', '')) + Number($(dragTarget).find('.cit-amount')[0].innerText.replace(',', ''))).toFixed(2));
        if (Number(recDiscrepancy.innerText) == 0){
            $(recDiscrepancy).removeClass('discrepancy-red');
            $(recDiscrepancy).addClass('discrepancy-green');
            $( discrepancyReason ).hide();
        }
        $(dragTarget).css({
            "position": "static",
            "background-color": "white",
            "margin": "5px",
            "border": "none",
            "box-shadow": "0 10px 10px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)",
            "border-radius": "5px"
        });
        // "Reactivating" draggable element, and redefinding dragTarget element to drag and drop elements back to CIT-Pickup table
        // Without it will rise bug, when draggable element become not draggable
        $( this ).find('.cit-pickup-row').draggable({
            start: function(){
                window.dragTarget = this;
                window.citTransactionId = $( dragTarget ).data('cit-transaction-id');
            },
            drag: function(event, ui){
                $( this ).css({
                    "position": "relative",
                    "margin": "0",
                    "border": "none",
                    "border-bottom": "1px solid #dfdfdf",
                    "border-radius": "0px"
                })
            }
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: citTransactions, а где этот массив?

Comment: Заполняется в другом месте

Comment: Вы убедитесь что массив не пустой. сделайте `console.log(your_arr.length)`. и посмотрите сколько там элементов вообще?

Comment: Да... откуда нам знать почему, если хз где он там наполняется

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan Делал `console.log`, выводит значения и заканчивает `1`

Comment: @Oleksandr Какое имеет значение, где он заполняется, если по факту в console.log выпадает, что он заполнен? Если вам так интересно, дополню сейчас вопрос

Comment: значение или количество?

Comment: сделайте лог в том цыкле

Comment: потому что твой `remove` меняет коллекцию по которой ты бежишь, но при этом счетчик не меняется

Comment: Вообще, в чем смысл кода: `for (j =0; j < citTransactions.length; j++) {
        citTransact = citTransactions[j];
        citTransactions.remove(citTransact);
    }`? Это равносильно удалению **всех** элементов, что можно сделать гораздо проще, например присваиванием переменной пустого массива

Comment: @Grundy Уже понял проблему, но всё равно спасибо. И да, я просто присвоил переменной пустой массив)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае метод `remove` можно заменить на вызов [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), и так как итерация в основном цикле идет не с конца, при удалении любого не последнего элемента следующий за ним элемент будет пропущен из-за сдвига индексов после удаления.

Как было отмечено в комментариях, вообще весь цикл, в котором вызывается `remove` удаляет *все* элементы из массива, что можно сделать намного проще, например присвоив переменной пустой массив, либо установив свойство `length` в значение `0`.

Так как внутри remove удаляются *все вхождения* элемента, то простой разворот цикла тут не поможет, но можно заменить сам цикл:

```js
Array.prototype.remove = function() {
  var what, a = arguments,
    L = a.length,
    ax;
  while (L && this.length) {
    what = a[--L];
    while ((ax = this.indexOf(what)) !== -1) {
      this.splice(ax, 1);
    }
  }
  return this;
};
var citTransactions = [3, 2, 3, 4, 3];
console.log(citTransactions);
for (var citTransact = citTransactions[0]; citTransactions.length; citTransact = citTransactions[0]) {
  citTransactions.remove(citTransact);
}
console.log(citTransactions);
```